# Interpretation of risk ratios for competing risk from AFT

Tags: survival, markov-process, regression-coefficients, competing-risks

I want to analyse the time to disease with a competing event with an accelerated failure time model (AFT) with Weibull distribution. I wonder how exactly we can interpret the resulting coefficients for the main event considering we have a competing event.
As an example using the dataset in library(mstate), I have patients that either develop AIDS or SI. I am interested in the time to AIDS, for the covariate ccr5WM, with the 'time ratio' from the AFT model = 1.366 for AIDS.

If it was not a competing risk model, I would say that the time to AIDS is 37% longer for patients with ccr5WM. Is this also correct for the competing risk model, keeping in mind that the model also estimates a coefficient for SI?

If anyone has a thought on this or a paper to share, I would very much appreciate it.

Note: I followed the [tutorial](http://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1002/sim.2712/abstract;jsessionid=8C0262C387787AFAA06AD64ADD5DCE1B.f03t01) for mstate  to create a long data format and define the model. And the paper [Survival Analysis Part II](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/12888808) by Bradburn, Clark, Love and Altman (2003) to understand the AFT model and am therefore asking whether the interpretation applies to competing risk as well.

---

Code to obtain the above result if someone wants to reproduce it:

```
library(mstate)
library(survival)
data("aidssi", package= "mstate")
dta = aidssi
head(dta)
```

For the multistate model, we need to transform the wide data into long data:

```
evt_label= c("No evt", "AIDS", "SI")
tmat = trans.comprisk(2,names=evt_label)
dta$stat1 = as.numeric(dta$status == 1)
dta$stat2 = as.numeric(dta$status == 2)
mycovar = "ccr5"
dta_long = msprep(time=c(NA,'time','time'),
   status = c(NA,'stat1','stat2'),data=dta,keep=mycovar,trans=tmat)
dta_long = expand.covs(dta_long, mycovar)
dta_long = transform(dta_long, endpt= evt_label[to])
```

The model fit for the AFT model with Weibull distribution and only for the transition to AIDS, but with competing risk SI, is done with the subset function:

```
fit = survreg(Surv(time, status) ~ ccr5WM.1, 
  subset(dta_long, trans==1), dist = "weibull")
```

With the results:

```
summary(fit)

Call:
survreg(formula = Surv(time, status) ~ ccr5WM.1, data = subset(dta_long, 
   trans == 1), dist = "weibull")
         Value Std. Error     z        p
(Intercept)  2.514     0.0566 44.40 0.00e+00
ccr5WM.1     0.312     0.1178  2.65 8.05e-03
Log(scale)  -0.692     0.0754 -9.18 4.38e-20

Scale= 0.501 

Weibull distribution
Loglik(model)= -417.3   Loglik(intercept only)= -421.3
Chisq= 7.91 on 1 degrees of freedom, p= 0.0049 
Number of Newton-Raphson Iterations: 7 
n=323 (6 observations deleted due to missingness)
```

Comment: When the question is predominantly about R rather than statistics it is off topic for this site.  It may be possible to get an answer by migrating to the Stack Overflow site.

Comment: I was asked to moved it here from Stack Overflow because it is a statistical question, unrelated to what language it is coded in.